# Custom Search Navigation notes per search results page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

Is it possible to have a search navigation webpart display different search verticals depending on which results page it's inserted on? For example on peopleresults.aspx I want other search navigation nodes than on the results.aspx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

- Add two search navigation webparts in the page
- Based on the current page, you can hide/show the search navigation webparts accordingly by writing a simple JavaScript that runs on page load.

For example , in case of peopleresults.aspx, show the search nav webpart for only Peopleresults and hide everything else.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not sure this solves my problem as the links are still the same. Inserting two webparts to a page will not make a difference as the links are configured in _layouts/15/enhancedSearch.aspx?level=site and each Search Navigation Webpart pulls from there. I guess I have to try to create a subsite for each page to get multiple endpoints for different links.